# How to configure flask-talisman for CDN scripts and cron jobs in python 3.11 standard google app engine

Tags: python-3.x, flask, google-app-engine, content-security-policy

Following the suggestion in the docs, I added flask-talisman but have run into two problems.

1. I'm using apexcharts from CDN and I don't know how to get the nonce right - otherwise I get an error on the style-src directive

-- main.py --

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='media')
# https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/flask-talisman#talisman-http-security-headers-for-flask
# https://content-security-policy.com/style-src/
csp = {
    # Assorted Google-hosted Libraries/APIs.
    'script-src': "'self' ajax.googleapis.com *.googleanalytics.com "
                  '*.google-analytics.com '
                  '*.googletagmanager.com '
                  'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts',
    'style-src': "'self' "
                'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts',
    'object-src': "'none'",
    'default-src': "'self' ",
    'connect-src': "'self' *.google-analytics.com appengine.googleapis.com",
}
_talisman = Talisman(app, content_security_policy=csp, content_security_policy_nonce_in=['script-src', 'style-src])

.
.
.
@app.get(r'/')
def main():
    ...
    context['nonce'] = _talisman._get_nonce()
    return render_template('list.html', context)
```

-- index.html --

```
<script nonce="{{ nonce }}" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>
<script nonce="{{ nonce }}" type="text/javascript">
// https://apexcharts.com/docs
var options = {
    series: _series,
    chart: {
...
```

2. I'm using cron jobs, but their with flask-talisman the trigger gets ignored without any errors I can find in the logs. I don't know where to start or what directive I need to apply on this one.

-- cron.yaml --

```
- description: "daily 25:20:25"
  url: /tasks/job/25/20/25
  schedule: every day 07:30
  timezone: America/New_York
```

-- tasks.py --

```
from flask import Blueprint
tasks_api = Blueprint('tasks', __name__)

@tasks_api.route(r'/job/<chunks>/<start>/<end>')
def get_job(chunks=25, start=0, end=5):
    pass
```

I verified the issue by forcing the cron trigger with and without wrapping my app in Talisman.

Answer (score 0):

(1) For the nonce, you need to add it to the CSP.  Use Chrome dev tools to see whether the nonce is getting added to your pages and if the nonce is the same that you are using in your templates.

I don't use Talisman, but I do something like this without Talisman:

```
nonce = token_urlsafe()
csp = f'"script-src 'self' 'nonce-{}' https://...'
_talisman = Talisman(app, content_security_policy=csp.format(nonce))
```

Hopefully that helps.

(2) For CRON jobs in GAE, you can't use https.  Talisman is probably redirecting http to https and than breaks the cron job handlers.

Comment: The dev tools show that I've passed the correct nonce (via template).  I solved the script-src directive errors that way - but the style-src error persists.  The error in Chrome flags one of the style modification routines like 'setAttribute' in the chart javascript.  I would like to figure this out but may just download and include the source in my project instead of using CDN. Thanks for your help.